# is there any possible way to share as a video from video url?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, share

I have video url which comes from server, I want to share video to other app (WhatsApp, Gmail) without download a video. I tried to below code but not working help if any possible solution..

```
        val videoUrl = extras!!.getString("VIDEO")
        val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        sharingIntent.type = "video/*"
        var uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl)
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Video!"))
```

Comment: Start by using a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard (i.e., replace `video/*` with the actual MIME type of the stream). But, in general, `EXTRA_STREAM` is supposed to contain a `Uri` pointing to a `ContentProvider`, so do not be surprised if apps reject something else (e.g., an `https` URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code snippet it works for me though I had implemented this over a year ago.

```
fun shareLocalVideo(title: String?, path: String) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, arrayOf(path),
            null
        ) { path, uri ->
            val shareIntent = Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_SEND
            )
            shareIntent.type = "video/*"
            shareIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title
            )
            shareIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title
            )
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            shareIntent
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
            startActivity(
                Intent.createChooser(
                    shareIntent,
                    "Share"
                )
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AbhiPatel, Could you please make it the correct answer if it works in the usual way?